This is how im trying to add a caption to my image in overleaf-latex but im getting that error that "\caption outside the float". How to resolve it?
\newpage

\onecolumn{\section{Proposed Model}} 

\vspace{5mm} %5mm vertical space

\begin{center}

    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{flowchart}\\

    \caption{Image Encryption Flowchart}

\end{center}


Your caption is, indeed, not in a float. Float environments are created by figure or table.
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\onecolumn{\section{Proposed Model}} 

\vspace{5mm}% 5mm vertical space

%\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}
    \caption{Image Encryption Flowchart}
\end{figure}
%\end{center}

\end{document}



this worked!! thankyou sm<3

No problem, happy to help. You can accept the answer then to mark your question as resolved :-).

the \section shouldn't be inside a group (\onecolumn does not have an argument)

See also \captionof{figure} from the caption or capt-of packages.
